# How do I remove up to a specified character from a string in Liquid?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to take a string such as `"Alpha - Bravo - Charlie"`, and remove characters up to and including the first `"-"`, leaving the result `"Bravo - Charlie"`.

I can't find a function that will return the position of a character.
I also can't find a function that will remove the first item from an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
{%- assign str = "Alpha - Bravo - Charlie" -%}
{%- assign str_parts = str | split: "-" -%}
{%- assign str_parts_size = str_parts | size -%}
{{- str_parts | slice: 1, str_parts_size | join: "-" -}}
```

Also, you can make it simpler by assuming a number of hyphens will never exceed a specific value e.g. **9**:

```
{{- "Alpha - Bravo - Charlie" | split: "-" | slice: 1, 9 | join: "-" -}}
```